# c# Winforms: Data skipped one row when exporting to datagridview in different form

Tags: c#, datagridview

My code below caused the data exported from richtextbox in Form 1 to skipped one row when displayed in datagridview in Form 2. I would like it to display at the first row.
[image: Unwanted output]

Below are my codes.

**Form 1**

```
namespace Delivery
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static string passingtext;
        public static string passingtext1;
        public static string passingtext2;
        public static string passingtext3;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormsCollection.Form2.Hide();
            passingtext = RichTextBox1.Text;
            passingtext1 = RichTextBox2.Text;
            passingtext2 = RichTextBox3.Text;
            passingtext3 = RichTextBox4.Text;
            Form2 dg = new Form2();
            FormsCollection.Form2.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**Form 2**

```
namespace Delivery
{
    public partial class Form2: Form
    {
        public static string passingtext;
        public static string passingtext1;
        public static string passingtext2;
        public static string passingtext3;
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void datagrid_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();
            row.Cells[0].Value = Todatagrid.passingtext;
            row.Cells[1].Value = Todatagrid.passingtext1;
            row.Cells[2].Value = Todatagrid.passingtext2;
            row.Cells[3].Value = Todatagrid.passingtext3;

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope to get some help thanks.

Comment: `DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();` It seems that there's already a row in your DataGrid and you're just adding more.

Comment: You can check the value of `dataGridView1.Rows.Count` before `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);` during debug to verify the contents of your grid view rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
   dataGridView1.Rows[0] = row;
```

or

```
  this.dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, row);
```

instead of

```
   dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: Hello precious. `this.dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, row);  ` worked well thanks. For `dataGridView1.Rows[0] = row;` lead to this error: **property or indexer 'DataGridViewRowCollection.this[int] cannot be assigned to -- it is read only**. Nevertheless, thanks so much for your help!